# Go to object in SSMS

Tags: sql-server

Is there a quick way, when selecting a table/view name in SQL Server Management Studio, to "go to" that object, or select it in the Object Explorer ?
A bit like Shift+F2 in VBE and F10 (not sure to remember) in Visual Studio ?

---

Edit: what I mean: while I am looking at (or editing) the code of a view in text mode (ALTER VIEW), if it contains the name a table or another view, I might want to quickly open that one, in order to see what it contains, or at least to be taken to the proper place in Object Explorer. That feature is available in Toad for SQL Server, and it's a nice time saver when you deal with several large database with hundreds of tables/views.

Comment: right click the table/view name and `SELECT TOP 1000 Rows`

Comment: Yes, there is a way of going to selected object using AutoHotKey tool, but I'm unable to write and test it right now. Custom AHK macro can (1) copy currently selected name into the clipboard, (2) switch to object tree and expand it and (3) type selected name so it becomes highlighted. I should be able to post the macro later.

Comment: @miroxlav interesting, you should make this an answer, even if it does not solve much if you can't install software on the machine you are using.

Comment: @M.Ali thanks but that's not the question. Considering your high reputationI am sure you can find better ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late, but I implemented a simple AutoHotKey macro as @miroxlav suggested in the comments.

```
^+0::
; Usage: highlight the name of the procedure (and nothing else) 
; and press the hotkey (currently Ctrl+Shift+0)

; The procedure should be in the format Database.Schema.Name

; For the object explorer to open consistently with F8, change 
; Tools --> Options --> Keyboard --> Keyboard --> "Apply the following additional..." 
; (top dropdown) to "Visual Studio 1010 Compatible"

ClipSaved := ClipboardAll

; Get name of the procedure into memory
Send {Left}
Send,{Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}{Right}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Up}  
Send ^c
clipwait
database := clipboard

Send {Right}
Send {Right}
Send,{Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}{Right}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Up}  
Send ^c
clipwait
section := clipboard

Send {Right}
Send {Right}
Send,{Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}{Right}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Up}  
Send ^c
clipwait
name := clipboard

; Switch to the object explorer and navigate to the procedure
Send {F8}
Sleep, 10

Send FIRST THREE LETTERS OF YOUR CONNECTION HERE ; Go to connection
Send {Right}

Send D ; Go to "Databases"
Send {Right}

send %database%
Send {Right}

Send Views
Send {Right}

Send Tables
Send {Right}

Send Progra ; Go to "Programmability"
Send {Right}

Send Stored ; go to "Stored Procedures"
Send {Right}

Send %section%
Send .
Send %name%

Clipboard := ClipSaved

return
```

Note that you should remove the all-caps text and replace it with the name of your primary database connection, i.e. what's at the very top of your object explorer. You should be able to use just the first few letters - for my purposes "pd" was enough but your situation will vary.

Tested with SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (11.0.2100.60) and Windows 10

Edit: you may need to add `Sleep, 30` after each `Send [text]` line in the object explorer-traversing section, depending on how fast your computer is. Sometimes AHK sends the `right` before SQL Server can highlight the correct object.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called SQLSmash that can accomplish this. 
http://www.sqlsmash.com/index.html
There's a free community edition. All editions come with a 'Go To Object' feature that lets you jump right to an object.

Comment: Hmm... I',m using SSMS 17.1 with SQLSmash and the "Go to object" feature hasn't worked for me for about a week (or ever)

Answer (score 0):

You can use right click on Tables or Views and select `Filter>Filter Settings` to quickly filter out from a long list of tables/sp/views.

I personally use arrow keys. Use the left and right arrows to expand collapse objects, and up/down to navigate.

Also if I remember table name and I want to quickly see details on table, then I type in and execute `sp_help <tablename>`.

Also you can always query designer using `Cntrl+Shift+Q`. Unlike object explorer you have tables names that do not begin with dbo(like `dbo.<tablename>`) and so we can always start typing in like in windows explorer and get to the table.

Comment: filtering can help a bit, if the names are such that you can use it, and if your source tables are in the same database. In my current contract, I write code in database B with source data in database A. I spend my time scrolling back and forward :-(

Comment: Here's a dirty trick! Open two instances of SSMS. And then use `Alt+tab` on Windows to switch between them